# Mover archivos con el mismo nombre en Python

Tags: python

Muy buenas a todos:

Vengo con un problema a ver si alguien es capaz de hallar la solución que yo no encuentro.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
import errno

source = r"C:\Users\Pasanus\Downloads\Captuars\Nueva carpeta"


destVae = r"H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\New"
if glob.glob(source + "\\*Vae Victis*"):
    for Archivos in glob.glob(source + "\\*Vae Victis*"):
        try:
            os.mkdir(destVae)
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
        shutil.move(Archivos, destVae)
    listaVae = os.listdir(destVae)
    os.rename(destVae, r'H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\\' +
              listaVae[0])
```

Lo que actualmente hace el código es:

CARPETA ORIGEN:
`C:\Users\Pasanus\Downloads\Captuars`

```
[A - Vae Victis.jpg, A - Vae Victis.rar, B1 - Vae Victis.jpg, B2 - Vae Victis.jpg, B - Vae Victis.rar, C+D - Vae Victis.jpg, C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar]`
```

CARPETA DESTINO:
`H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\A - Vae Victis`

```
[A - Vae Victis.jpg, A - Vae Victis.rar, B1 - Vae Victis.jpg, B2 - Vae Victis.jpg, B - Vae Victis.rar, C+D - Vae Victis.jpg, C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar]`
```

Lo que buscamos que haga el código es:

`H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\A - Vae Victis`

```
[A - Vae Victis.jpg, A - Vae Victis.rar]
```

`H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\B - Vae Victis`

```
[B1 - Vae Victis.jpg, B2 - Vae Victis.jpg, B - Vae Victis.rar]
```

`H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis\C+D+E - Vae Victis`

```
[C+D - Vae Victis.jpg, C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar]
```

Espero haber podido ser más aclaratorio. Muchas gracias ^^

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿requieres mover todos los archivos a una carpeta, excepto los que tengan el mismo nombre exacto, porque esos se deben mover a una nueva carpeta que debe llamarse como ellos?

Comment: Mejor haz un ejemplo con texto, un antes y un después. No está claro lo que pides.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, a ver si asi me logro explicar un poco mejor XD

Comment: Por favor, pon un ejemplo en formato **texto** con los directorios antes y después de la operación.

Comment: @CandidMoe Creo que pide que todos los archivos que tengan vae victis se muevan a la carpeta que se llame como sujeto el nombre del archivo y complemento vae victis, por ejemplo cupo 1 - Vae Victis.png, cupo 1 - Vae Victis.jpg, cupo 2 - Vae Victis.rar. se debe mover a una carpeta llamada cupo Vae Victis, Pero si hay archivos con diferentes nombres y con la palabra Vae Victis entonces guardarlo en capetas con el nombre + Vae Victis

Comment: Ejemplo: cupo 1 - Vae Victis.png, cupo 1 - Vae Victis.jpg, cupo 2 - Vae Victis.rar, Prueba - Vae Victis.jpg, Prueba 2 - Vae victis.png, Prueba 3 - Vae Victis.png, prueba - Vae Victis.rar . Deben ser movido a: Cupo Vae Victis :  [cupo 1 - Vae Victis.png, cupo 1 - Vae Victis.jpg, cupo 2 - Vae Victis.rar], Prueba Vae Victis: [Prueba - Vae Victis.jpg, Prueba 2 - Vae victis.png, Prueba 3 - Vae Victis.png, prueba - Vae Victis.rar]

Comment: @DanielBriceño. Soy un hombre de palabras. Dame texto, no imagenes. (Correctamente formateado).

Comment: @CandidMoe Si... No soy el que pregunta

Comment: @DanielBriceño. Inconfundible. Digo que espero que el OP tome tu ejemplo, lo valide y agregue a la pregunte convenientemente formateado.

Comment: Vale, creo entonces que no entiendo lo de ejemplo en formato texto, pero voy a intentarlo a ver si puedo explicarme. Edito para explicarlo con texto.

Comment: Te enseñaré una manera mas visual de escribirlo, solo que aqui no me sale saltos de líneas: Has un print con esto: print("url/name_dir/\n    - name_dir_2/\n    - Name_dir_3/\n        - Name file.png\n    - name_file.png\n    - name file_2.jpg")

Answer (score 1):

A según puedo entender, lo que quieres es catalogar los archivos según el comienzo del nombre del archivo + `Vae Victis`, **sin incluír números**, o sea, algo así:

```
Origen: 
[C:\Users\Pasanus\Downloads\Captuars]
 |- "A - Vae Victis.jpg" 
 |- "A - Vae Victis.rar" 
 |- "B1 - Vae Victis.jpg"
 |- "B2 - Vae Victis.jpg" 
 |- "B - Vae Victis.rar"
 |- "C+D - Vae Victis.jpg"
 |- "C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar"
    
Destino: 
[H:\Plasencia\3D\REVISADOS\Tabletop\Nueva carpeta\Vae Victis]
 |-  [A - Vae Victis]
 |    |- "A - Vae Victis.jpg" 
 |    |- "A - Vae Victis.rar"
 |-  [B - Vae Victis]
 |    |- "B1 - Vae Victis.jpg"
 |    |- "B2 - Vae Victis.jpg" 
 |    |- "B - Vae Victis.rar"
 |-  [C+D - Vae Victis]
      |- "C+D - Vae Victis.jpg"
      |- "C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar"
```

Lo que se me ocurre es leer nombre por nombre y si tiene `Vae Victis` entonces se extrae la primera parte de la cadena y se le suma la segunda parte, `Vae Vitis`. En algunas ocasiones la cadena trae un número, entonces se pasa por un filtro para eliminarlo:

```py
>>> cad = "C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar"
>>> pos_vae_vic = cad.lower().find('vae victis')
>>> nombre_dir = cad[:pos_vae_vic+10]
>>> nombre_dir
'C+D1 - Vae Victis'
>>> ''.join([x for x in nombre_dir if not x.isdigit()]) # Quitar num
'C+D - Vae Victis'
```

Listo, con eso se puede construir el código.
[*] Con las líneas comentadas está en modo *"test"*, descomentar para que funcione.

```py
import os
import shutil

path_src = r'C:\Dir\Origen'
path_dst = r'H:\Dir\Destino'

# La siguiente es una lista de pruebas, eliminar
lista_archivos = ["prueba1.jpg", "A - Vae Victis.jpg", "A - Vae Victis.rar", 
    "B1 - Vae Victis.jpg", "B2 - Vae Victis.jpg", "B - Vae Victis.rar", 
    "C+D - Vae Victis.jpg", "C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar", "prueba2.rar", "prueba3.jpg"]

# lista_archivos = os.listdir(path_src) # <-- Descomentar
    
for cfile in lista_archivos:
    cfile_low = cfile.lower()
    pos_vae_vic = cfile_low.find('vae victis')
    if pos_vae_vic > 0:
        dst_name = cfile[:pos_vae_vic+10]
        dst_noNums = ''.join([x for x in dst_name if not x.isdigit()])
        dir_dst = os.path.join(path_dst, dst_noNums)
        #os.makedirs(dir_dst, exist_ok=True) # <-- Descomentar
        src = os.path.join(path_src, cfile)
        dst = os.path.join(dir_dst, cfile)
        print(f'{src} --> {dst}')
        #shutil.move(src, dst) # <-- Descomentar
```

La salida de esto es:

```
C:\Dir\Origen\A - Vae Victis.jpg --> H:\Dir\Destino\A - Vae Victis\A - Vae Victis.jpg
C:\Dir\Origen\A - Vae Victis.rar --> H:\Dir\Destino\A - Vae Victis\A - Vae Victis.rar
C:\Dir\Origen\B1 - Vae Victis.jpg --> H:\Dir\Destino\B - Vae Victis\B1 - Vae Victis.jpg
C:\Dir\Origen\B2 - Vae Victis.jpg --> H:\Dir\Destino\B - Vae Victis\B2 - Vae Victis.jpg
C:\Dir\Origen\B - Vae Victis.rar --> H:\Dir\Destino\B - Vae Victis\B - Vae Victis.rar
C:\Dir\Origen\C+D - Vae Victis.jpg --> H:\Dir\Destino\C+D - Vae Victis\C+D - Vae Victis.jpg
C:\Dir\Origen\C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar --> H:\Dir\Destino\C+D - Vae Victis\C+D1 - Vae Victis.rar
```

Referencias: [Removing numbers from string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851835/1545868)

Comment: Ala!! Muchisimas gracias, verdaderamente funciona! ahora voy a intentar estudiar el código a fondo para entenderlo bien y poder replicarlo muchas veces más. Muchas gracias ^^

Comment: Me alegro te haya servido @IsidoroPlasencia. Si la consideras útil, puedes marcar la respuesta como Aceptada. Saludos.